# Some labels appear in ArcMap while others do not

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling

I am using ArcMap.

I'm using a template from someone who previously created maps.
I am simply applying labels to xy points but for some reason only some of the labels appear whiles others don't.

Why is this the case?

Here is an image below. It seems like when I reduce the font size, the more labels appear. I don't want to go smaller than what I have right now.

[image]

Comment: Are you using the Maplex or Standard Labeling Engine?  What version of ArcMap are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You need to force all labels to show up using the 'Never Remove (place overlapping) option:
https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/working-with-text/forcing-the-placement-of-all-labels-in-a-label-class.htm

Answer (score 0):

There are two main options.

1. If you are adding new layers to the project, you must indicate the software to display the labels. To do so, right click on the layer > Properties > Labels tab > Check the 'Label features in this layer'option > Select and configure the field you want to display > Accept or Apply
2. Could be related to labels conflict. Bassically, the software has predefined rules on how to display labels in each layer and between them. To solve this, take a look on the [Maplex section](https://desktop.arcgis.com/es/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-text/a-quick-tour-of-maplex.htm) for the ArcMap version you are using.